# How to use Java API code in Camunda Platform in order to describe BPMN process and then deploy the war in Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, camunda

I am using for the first time the Camunda Platform. Here is what I would like to do:

- write a BPMN model (with Camunda Modeler using the eclipse plugin)
- then write some java code that will explain and describe the service tasks, the user tasks, and so on, of the process
- and then deploy it as war file inside Tomcat
- then use REST webservice to communicate with it and get information about process, tasks, user etc..

My problem here is that I don't understand how to write Java code using the Camunda classes. I have read the documentation abount JavaDelegation, Process Application, and I did the easy tutorial but I am confused. I don't know where to start to develop. Sorry if I make silly questions.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the 'simple process'-tutorial at http://docs.camunda.org/latest/guides/getting-started-guides/developing-process-applications/ ?

More advanced tutorials are available at http://camunda.org/examples/.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. yes I've already done the first tutorial and I saw all the examples but there isn't a representation from BPMN syntax to Java code, that's what I need. Any other example please?

Comment: @eric What do you mean with _representation from BPMN syntax to Java code_? Could you give an example? You model the process using BPMN and use Java to implement the logic of service tasks for example.

Comment: @Sebastian That's exactly the point. I don't know how to implement the logic of all types of tasks (service task, user task and so on) using Java. I need to use java to check the state of the process, to store the various states of the process, or to check the owner of a task and so on..How can I do this using the bpmn platform framework?I'm refering to this link:https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform. Sorry if my questions are confusing but I'm new with Camunda Platform

Comment: @eric A user task is a task which is executed manually by a user. The BPM engine only has to be notified when the user finished the task (eg using the [Tasklist](http://docs.camunda.org/7.2/guides/user-guide/#tasklist)). If you want to examine the state of the process inside a java delegate you can use the [camunda service API](http://docs.camunda.org/7.2/guides/user-guide/#process-engine-process-engine-api-services-api). Maybe we can discuss your issues better in the [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/camunda-bpm-users)